# How to Install Netbeans Enterprise 5.5 upon Netbeans IDE 6.5

Tags: netbeans

Netbeans IDE standard edition 6.5 is already installed in my computer. Now, I have to install Netbeans Enterprise Edition 5.5 upon it. But i could not do so. Can anyone help in this regard?

Comment: What do you mean with "upon it"? You can easily download NetBeans zip, decompress it and run the binary as any other Java app independently of any previous versions and even using a different JVM.

Comment: it means without uninstalling the existing netbeans IDE 6.5 , i hav to install netbeans enterprise edition 5.5